# where does signal handler executed?

Tags: linux, signals

I am confused with the execution about signal handler.

Assuming that i run a single thread(main thread) with a signal handler registered for SIGTERM. Then when the signal SIGTERM is received, does the handler executed in the current thread(main thread) or in another separated thread apart from the main thread.

ANSWER:
i have read a blog about signal handler and reentrant functions. [here is the address.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-reent/)

Comment: Actually, you should define precisely what you mean by *threads*. Stricto sensu, the kernel does not know user threads (e.g. those started with `pthread_create`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch While this is pretty much true in current Linux, which the question has tagged, do note that it hasn't always been that way, and it isn't necessarily true across all *nixen. Solaris in particular, in some versions had/has an NxM user-thread to kernel-thread (i.e. schedulable entity) model, in contrast to Linux's current "entirely in user space" pthread implementation...

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, the signal handler is executed in the current thread (assuming you mean a scheduled task running that thread, since the kernel scheduler only schedules tasks).

Usually, when a signal is sent, the kernel automagically sets up some call frame(s) for the signal handler (the newly added frames end with `sigreturn` ...)

See also [sigaltstack(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaltstack.2.html) & [sigreturn(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigreturn.2.html)

Notice that [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) is not a syscall (see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...) and is not known to the kernel (since `pthread_create` is calling [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html)). Read [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) and [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

BTW, details are probably different on various POSIX systems (Linux, MacOSX, Solaris, ...)

Comment: if the signal handler is executed in the current thread, the thread that register the handler, then the work in that thread will be blocked and will be resumed later if possible. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, this is almost by definition of signal handling. You should read all the references I gave you above.